# Is it possible to become a millionaire in $ with online poker?

Tags: online

I am sure this have been asked in various ways in plenty of internet forums but I ask it in a rough way:

can someone starts - say with 500 USD and build gains in ONLINE poker ( and only in online poker ) , eventually having some people financing him/her at some stage of his/her career , untill he/she reaches millions of USD in gains? And this in the space of a few years?

Is it something that happened in the past. . are they known online poker millionaires that built their money only and solely from online poker?

Comment: I did, so it is certainly possible :-)

Comment: The world's is full of poker millionaires, although these guys put an exceptional dedication for this. So instead of it's possible or not, the better question is how much it takes and if you're willing to play say 5k tournaments per year and do serious work with yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly this can theoretically be done. The games are harder than they were 10 years ago, but it's possible to be a profitable player, and if you're profitable all you need is more time and tables.

Here's one example of a player who as a proof of concept started with a small bankroll with the intent of working it up to a nice sum of 100K in a short time. He ultimately didn't quite get there, but it was close, and as a nice bonus he donated the money to charity. It's not a million dollars, but you get the point!

http://www.pokerstarsblog.com/en/blog/team_pokerstars_online/2013/andre-coimbra-sets-out-for-on-100-to-100-125935.html

Another nice artifact of Andre's 100K challenge is this set of youtube coaching videos he and Andrew Brokos made:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3zKVIJFdQk